# Simulation of reflection of microstructures

Tags: simulation

I want to simulate the reflection of a 2D array of sub-wavelength sized features. I would like to simulate the reflection of the microstructures.

I am looking for a free software which would enable me to do such such simulation.

Maybe a RCWA code... but I would be nice, if it is user friendly or at least has some decent tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

This basically answers your questions for the tutorials:
https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_anybody_help_me_on_RCWA_matlab_code_for_TM_polarization

...and:
https://www.researchgate.net/post/which_other_open_source_or_in_any_case_free_implementations_of_FDTD_and_RCWA_are_available_and_to_compare_their_capabiities

And here is a free software, if you have Matlab:
http://rawdogapp.weebly.com/screenshots.html

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That's exactley what I was looking for !

Comment: No problem... just needed to google a bit.